# call the construct class again trough another function of the class in PHP?

Tags: php, constructor, construct

I want to call the __construct function again in my class

something like this:

```
class user{
    function __construct($ID = null)
    {
        if($ID){
            //code
        }

    function findUser()
    {
        //code
        $this->__construct($ID);
    }
}
```

of course this does not work, but what is the correct way to do this?

Comment: `$this->__construct($ID)` will work, you need to call the function by its name. Of course, the constructor should only be called once. [@zerkms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505542/call-the-construct-class-again-trough-another-function-of-the-class-in-php/4505560#4505560) has the right answer.

Comment: It wouldn't work because you missed out the two underscores.

Comment: that's a typo :) I just fixed it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to overwrite the current values in the current instance, I would do this:

```
class user{
    function __construct($ID = null)
    {
        $this->reinit($ID);
    }

    function reinit($id)
    {
        if($id) {
            //code
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: fixed it, sorry, my PHP is shaky, haven't used it in a while

Answer (score 5):

```
class user{
    function __construct($ID = null)
    {
        if($ID){
            //code
        }

    static function find($id)
    {
        return new user($id);
    }
}

$user = user::find(42);
```

Comment: +1 This is the way to go if you intend to apply something like the factory pattern.

Comment: this works but it would be more complecated for me to do it this way, because my function also returns a true or false if the user is found or not. so I used codeThis' method and return true when the user is found and call an init function

Comment: @mars: if user is not found - return null, otherwise return user instance. After that you can just check `is_null($user)` to see, if it was found or not.

Answer (score 3):

Rename the function so that you can call it:

```
class user {
    function __construct($ID = null)
    {
        $this->initialize($ID);
    }

    private function initialize($ID = null)
    {
        if($ID){
            //code
    }

    function findUser()
    {
        //code
        $this->initialize($ID);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function findUser(){

   self::__construct($ID);
}
```